# Resurrect named NPC for use in quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I took part in a drinking contest with a stranger in an inn, and instead of waking up in a wrecked temple, he just took his barstool again, and only responded with "huh?", "Hmm?", etc. when I spoke to him.

I looked up the details of the quest line, and with further investigation, it appears that Ysolda has somehow died. I used the console and did a `player.moveto [RefId]` and found her corpse in that odd green-and-purple-bricked dead zone.

Since I missed the window directly after her death to use `resurrect 1` to keep her alive in the minds of the town, can I use any console-fu to repair the quest line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the console to skip past that stage of the quest by typing this into the console:

> setstage DA14 40

Other quest stages are available (SPOILERS) [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember)