# Which Daedric Artifacts are missable by killing someone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

In my last save, when I was an orc, I unlocked all Daedric artifacts, except two. I could not get the "Sanguine Rose", and I read somewhere it was because I killed a women out of Whiterun by the name of Ysolda. I had the drinking contest with Sam, and I did not black out. And the other, the "Rueful Axe", I received when I killed Barbas, the dog you encounter outside of Falkreath when you talk to Lod, the town blacksmith. I completed the quest and killed him, instead of waiting and getting the actual artifact. Is there a way, after having received the Rueful Axe, to get the helmet instead? And is there a way to get the quest to get the Sanguine Rose?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you DO need to kill the priest in Dawnstar at the end of the quest else he destroys one of the artifacts.

Comment: Which quest would that be? For the helmet, or the rose?

Comment: @MolagBal Vaermina's Skull of Corruption.

Comment: You can, through careful killing, get both Savior's Hide and Ring of Hircine though. Both count towards the achievement, so you can still get it even if you mess *one* other up.

Comment: Ah, Yes.. I will reload from that point and get both. But how do I get the Rose? I have had the drinking contest, but I did not black out.

Comment: And I have all others, just not the Sanguine Rose and the Helm. I accidentally killed Barbas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, [PS3Trophies](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/guide/) list five of them as *missable*. Here is the list:

- **Mehrunes’ Razor**
  Sometime in the game you’ll get a message from a courier to visit the museum in Dawnstar – visit it. Visit it even if you don’t and start the “Pieces of the Past” quest to get your hands on Mehrunes’ Razor, which will send you to three places in Skyrim to get the three pieces of the sword.? You must kill Silus at the end to get the artefact.
- **Savior’s Hide**
  In Falkreath at the Falkreath Barracks (east of town), downstairs in the Falkreath jail you’ll find a chap called Sinding who will give you his cursed ring and thus starts the quest, “Ill Met by Moonlight.”
  Again, like the rest, you must choose to kill or risk not getting the reward.
  You cannot have the Ring of Hircine and Savior's Hide. You must kill Sinding instead of helping him. Thanks to jamby for the info.
  It is possible to get both Savior's Hide and the Ring of Hircine and have them both count. You will have to kill the hunters and then go back and kill Sinding. Thanks to Rawra for confirming.
- **Masque of Clavicus Vile**
  The first time you enter Falkreath through the front gate the guard will mention something about the blacksmith’s dog going missing. Speak to him and then go after the dog. When you meet the dog you’ll initiate the “A Daedra’s Best Friend” quest and head off to Haemar’s Shame at the south of the large mountain with High Hrothgar on it – east of Helgen – note: you have to follow the dog but he has terrible path finding, so you could just meet him there.
  You’ll then set off to retrieve The Rueful Axe from Rimrock Burrow and return it.
  NOTE: Do NOT kill Barbas with the axe when you return, give it back to Clavicus and get the Daedric masque.
- **Skull of Corruption**
  If you head to the Windpeak Inn in Dawnstar you’ll see a bit of a situation arise with locals speaking to Erandur regarding some night terrors they’ve been having. Speak to Erandur and start the “Waking Nightmare” quest.
  It’s a simple follow him, go here, go there trophy (note: the Dreamstride book is on the balcony area in the far corner) but at the end when you get the chance to kill Erandur whilst he’s performing the ritual, kill him and you’ll get the Skull of Corruption. If you don’t, he destroys it.
- **Ring of Namira**
  In Markarth, in the Understone Keep you’ll find a priest called Verulus who wants you to head into the Hall of the Dead to investigate what’s going on. The quest starts off as a miscellaneous objective and will soon turn into the quest, “The Taste of Death” once you’ve spoken to and agreed to help Eola in clearing Reachcliff Cave. There is a potential that you could say no to helping Eola… don’t!
  In order to get the ring you have to kill Verulus as he lies on the table and then eat his flesh.

Now, for what you put in the body, jwaddell just answered and I don't think I can add more.  You can still try what Daniel suggests in his comment on your question, which seems to be the only way to get the 15 items if you're not on a PC...!

Comment: So, You're saying that I do not need any of the above to get the trophy/achievement Oblivion Walker?

Comment: @MolagBal Nope. It means that this trophy is missable if you mess one of these quests above by doing the wrong choice.

Answer (score 3):

Ysolda is an integral part of the [A Night To Remember](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember) quest (which awards the Sanguine Rose), so if she is dead then you won't be able to start the quest.

If you're on PC, you could use the console to get around the problem (from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40198/1561)):

```
setstage DA14 40
```