# How many Daedric artificts are in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How many Daedric artifacts are in Skyrim, and what are their names?

Daedric artifacts are the rewards you get for completing certain Daedric quests. Some of them are the Mace of Molag Bal and Dawnbreaker. I do not know most of their names, and I am trying to get the platinum trophy for Skyrim, and one of the trophies are to get all of the Daedric artifacts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Literally the first result when searching for ["list of deadric artifacts in skyrim"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Quests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 16 [Daedric Artifacts](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daedric_Artifacts_%28Skyrim%29) possible in Skyrim.

**Azura's Star or The Black Star**

This reusable soul gem is rewarded for completing ["The Black Star"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Star_(Quest)) quest.

**Dawnbreaker**

This One-Handed sword is rewarded for completing ["The Break of Dawn"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Break_of_Dawn) quest.

**Ebony Blade**

This Two-Handed sword is rewarded for completing ["The Whispering Door"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Whispering_Door) quest.

**Ebony Mail**

This piece of unique armor is rewarded for completing ["Boethiah's Calling"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Boethiah%27s_Calling) quest.

**Mace of Molag Bal**

This unique one-handed weapon is rewarded for completing ["The House of Horrors"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_House_of_Horrors) quest.

**Masque of Clavicus Vile**

This unique Heavy Armor helm is rewarded for completing ["A Daedra's Best Friend"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend) quest, but only if the Dragonborn chooses to give Vile his axe instead of using it to kill Barbas.

**Mehrunes' Razor**

This unique dagger is rewarded for completing the ["Pieces of the Past"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pieces_of_the_Past) quest, but only if the Dragonborn kills Silus when Dagon tells him to.

**Oghma Infinium**

The Oghma Infinium is a powerful tome of knowledge that is rewarded for completing the ["Discerning the Transmundane"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane).

**Ring of Namira**

This ring is rewarded for completing ["The Taste of Death"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Taste_of_Death) quest.

**Sanguine Rose**

This unique staff is rewarded for completing ["A Night to Remember"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Night_to_Remember) quest.

**Savior's Hide and/or Ring of Hircine**

Either of these items is a potential reward for completing ["Ill Met by Moonlight" quest"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ill_Met_by_Moonlight), in a certain manner.

**Skeleton Key**

The Skeleton Key is the only Daedric Artifact known not to count for the achievement, Oblivion Walker. It is obtained during the Thieves Guild quest ["Blindsighted."](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blindsighted)

**Skull of Corruption**

This unique staff is rewarded for completing ["Waking Nightmare"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Nightmare) quest, but only if you kill Erandur in the quest.

**Spellbreaker**

This unique shield is rewarded for completing ["The Only Cure"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Only_Cure) quest.

**Volendrung**

This unique warhammer is rewarded for completing ["The Cursed Tribe"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cursed_Tribe) quest in Largashbur.

**Wabbajack**

This unique staff is rewarded for completing ["The Mind of Madness"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mind_of_Madness).

**TAKE NOTE**:, [some of them are missable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47612/which-daedric-artifacts-are-missable-by-killing-someone), so be careful.

Comment: Just gonna note *it is possible for you to get both the saviors hide and the ring of hircine*